# MySQL Opening closing balance with date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `transactions` in my MySQL database with 50K records. The data looks like below.

```
trx_date    bill        due
2020-03-01  100.00      10.00
2020-03-02   50.00      20.00   
2020-03-02  100.00       0.00  
2020-03-03  200.00      30.00  
2020-03-04  100.00      10.00
...
...
```

My goal is to show the query result with query parameters `from_date` and `to_date`

from the starting date of table opening will be 0 and calculation will be

`opening(+)   bill (+)   due (-)   closing = ( opening+bill ) - due`

```
trx_date    opening     bill        due     closing
2020-03-01  0           100.00      10.00    90.00
2020-03-02  90.00       50.00       20.00   120.00     
2020-03-02  120.0       100.00       0.00   220.00
2020-03-03  220.00      200.00      20.00   400.00  
2020-03-04  400.00      110.00      10.00   500.00
....
....
```

I can't figure out what is the optimal way to get the previous date `closing` for my selected from_date `opening`.

`from_date=2020-03-03` and `to_date=2020-03-04`

```
trx_date    opening     bill        due     closing    
2020-03-03  220.00      200.00      20.00   400.00  
2020-03-04  400.00      110.00      10.00   500.00
```

Here my point is how I can get opening `220.00` from the previous result? For getting 220.00 from the previous result there could be thousands of records, so that what will be the best practice?

Comment: how are you calculating `opening` and `closing`? or it is already in the table?

Comment: Please provide the SQL statement(s) you have already tried.

Comment: min date = opening 0
opening(+)   bill (+)   due (-)   closing = ( opening+bill ) - due

Comment: What is YOUR MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL version 5.7.24

Comment: That is not a complete SQL statement. Please edit your question to show the complete SQL statement you have tried, and which you need help with.

Comment: Your dataset does not allow to obtain deterministic result - the ordering by `trx_date` is not unique. You MUST specify unique ordering criteria.

Comment: *how I can get opening 220.00 from the previous result? For getting 220.00 from the previous result there could be thousands of records, so that what will be the best practice?* Calculate starting balances for each date into separate table once, than use this data as base balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SET @fromDate='2020-03-03', @toDate='2020-03-04';
SET @minDate = (SELECT MIN(trx_date) FROM transactions);
SET @previousDate=DATE_SUB(@fromDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);

SELECT trx_date,@balance opening, bill, due, @balance := @balance + bill - due closing
FROM transactions, (SELECT @balance := (SELECT SUM(bill)-SUM(due) FROM transactions WHERE trx_date BETWEEN @minDate AND @previousDate)) variable
WHERE trx_date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate ORDER BY trx_date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute all the `opening` and `closing` values starting from the first `trx_date`, and then filter the results by the dates you are interested in:

```
SELECT trx_date, opening, bill, due, closing
FROM (
  SELECT trx_date, 
         @balance AS opening,
         bill,
         due,
         @balance := @balance + bill - due AS closing
  FROM transactions
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0) ini
  ORDER BY trx_date
) tx
WHERE trx_date BETWEEN '2020-03-03' AND '2020-03-04'
```

Output:

```
trx_date    opening     bill    due     closing
2020-03-03  220         200     20      400
2020-03-04  400         110     10      500
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xx2cjamKE1SpKAXyMrDXAY/0)

Comment: Your query helps me a lot in making stock report, but I have some problems. The problem is regarding opening stock should be zero respect for each product and product type. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Rudrakshya if you just use the subquery that should give you your desired result. If not, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Formally:

```
SELECT @balance opening, bill, due, @balance := @balance + bill - due closing
FROM source_table, (SELECT @balance := 0) variable
/* ORDER BY trx_date */
;
```

But there is no unique criteria in shown sample data - so the result is not deterministric.

Comment: Thanks for the response. With this query, It always opening balance starts with `0` for any date range. Please read my question last part

Comment: @Akashkhan Alter starting balance in `variable` subquery from 0 to the value which you need.